# Popular songs with samba whistle (or similar) to signal transition?

Tags: rock, pop

I'm looking for examples from popular music of any era where a [samba whistle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apito) (either a proper *apito de samba*, a common coach's/referee's whistle, or something with a similar sound) is used at a point in the song where there is a sudden change in tempo, rhythm, timbre, etc.

Two examples are "Fool in the Rain" by Led Zeppelin (at 2:28 and 3:29-3:45)

and "Paradise City" by Guns N' Roses (at 1:20)

Answer (score 0):

At about 3:05 of J. Geils' Give it To mE

Answer (score 0):

Ying Yang twins - Halftime starts with a samba whistle

Osibisa - Wango Wango has one at 0:04